# Canon pixma MG3250 prints blank pages only

Tags: drivers, printing, dell, laptop, canon

I have a wireless Canon pixma MG3250 printer but when I print via my new linux laptop running ubuntu 20.04.01 it prints blank pages only.

The print head moves along like it's printing properly but it's just blank.

I've tried setting to colour only and then monochrome only but it's the same result.

The printer works fine when I print wirelessly from a windows laptop and also an iphone.

Any ideas people?

Thanks in advance, James.

Comment: Did you install drivers?

Comment: Through settings on the laptop I clicked add printer and took it from there. I haven't installed anything else I didn't know I needed to. Printer appears to work but it's blank pages only. Where would I find a driver to make it work and how would I install it?

Comment: Have you tried changing your ink cartridges? If not, [check out this guide](https://printerdeets.com/canon-printer-printing-blank-pages/) on how you can solve when your Canon printer gives a blank page error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Final updated answer:***
Create a folder on your desktop called canon-mg3250

```
sudo apt install libtiff5
cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250
```

Download the drivers from `https://id.canon/en/support/0100466601` and `https://id.canon/id/support/0100470101` and move them into the canon-mg3250 folder.

```
cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250/cnijfilter-mg3200series-3.80-1-deb
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install libpng12-0
./install.sh
```

You will be prompted to make sure your printer is switched ON and connected to your router, then to hit enter to continue, then enter “2” for “Network” and press enter. It should search and find your printer. Then follow the on screen instructions. Proceed to System → Administration → Printers to configure the printer using the newly acquired drivers unless install.sh configured this automatically.

Comment: Hi Edmund, thank you for trying to help. I'm new to linux and I'm struggling. I've done the first bit and created the folder on the desktop. I've opened terminal and done the first and second commands that you suggested. Fist of all it says unable to install libtiff4. Both the commands starting with tar and the final command with cd don't do anything. I get an error message saying 'Cannot open: No such file or directory tar Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Sorry, use `sudo apt install libtiff5`. Then enter the canon-mg3250 folder in terminal. Then you have to download the drivers online first and move it to the canon-mg3250 folder before you run the commands starting with tar.

Comment: Download the drivers from `https://id.canon/en/support/0100466601` and `https://id.canon/id/support/0100470101`

Comment: Hi Edmund, thank you I really appreciate your help but I'm still failing. I downloaded the two files from canon that you provided links for. I then extracted them and saved the folders into the desktop canon-mg3250 folder. Then I did the sudo apt install libtiff5, then the cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250, then I tried to run each tar file in turn. But I still get the error cannot open no such file or directory. I'm sorry I'm so rubbish, it's probably really simple for you. Do I need to do anything with the extracted files first or just put them in the desktop folder? Thank you, James

Comment: The canon folder on the desktop now contains two folders one with the names exactly as showing on the commands you gave me apart from they end in deb rather than deb.tar.gz  But the terminal still says no such file or directory.

Comment: Try `tar xvzf` instead of `tar xvf` for the two commands

Comment: Fail, sorry.tar (child): cnijfilter-mg3200series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now and tar (child): scangearmp-mg3200series-2.00-1-deb.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your canon-mg3250 folder

Comment: Hi Edmund,
Thanks for still trying, I'm new to ubuntu and there's a few things that don't seem very intuitive, like how to add a screenshot to this discussion!

So I've done a bodge and although there's probably a better way of doing it I've uploaded to Imgur. I hope you can see it, if you can't then get back to me and I'll try something else.

https://imgur.com/SRTdOES

Cheers,

Comment: I didn't know that the folders were already extracted for you. Try `cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250/cnijfilter-mg3200series-3.80-1-deb` then
`./install.sh`

Comment: Ooh close!!

It did the first bit but then not quite. I've screenshot the entire thing.

https://imgur.com/3OjhN6q and https://imgur.com/izT6sNO

Thank you again for this I know it's a pain but I do appreciate it.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12` then `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install libpng12-0`

Comment: OK lovely thank you. I'm a bit confused as to what I'm doing now in what order. Is it?:

sudo apt-get install libtiff5 then
cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250 then
sudo apt update then
sudo apt install libpng12-0

Comment: If you have installed libtiff5 once then no need to do it again. `cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250/cnijfilter-mg3200series-3.80-1-deb` to enter the folder. Then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12` then `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install libpng12-0` then `./install.sh`.

Comment: Thanks Edmund I'll try that. No.1 son has an online school lesson now so I can't try the printer and see what happens but:
#=========================================================#
Installation has been completed.
Printer Name : MG3250
Select this printer name for printing.
#=========================================================#

I'm very hopeful, no errors seem to have popped up so 'hank you.

Comment: No problem, just glad to help

Comment: While I think about it if it does work do I need to keep the canon folder on my desktop can it be deleted?

Finally I have more than once account on this laptop so the kids can do their schoolwork, do I need to repeat this process on each account or not?

Kind regards, James.

Comment: If it does work, that means the drivers have been installed, so you can delete the folder if you want, but I advise against it since you might need it in future when the same problem occurs. I am not sure if you have to repeat this process on each account because I only have one account on my linux machine.

Comment: Edmund it worked!!! Thank you so much for all your help, I really want you to know how grateful I am. Thank you. James.

Comment: I saved this thread in an email in the canon folder and I've taken it from the desktop and put it away safe. Tried it on another account and it worked fine. Thanks for everything.

Comment: No problem, just glad to help

Comment: So this is what worked in the end:

Create a folder on your desktop called canon-mg3250

Download the drivers from canon at https://id.canon/en/support/0100466601 and https://id.canon/id/support/0100470101

Extract the files into the desktop folder.

Then:

sudo apt-get install libtiff5

cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250

cd ~/Desktop/canon-mg3250/cnijfilter-mg3200series-3.80-1-deb to enter the folder.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12

sudo apt update

sudo apt install libpng12-0

./install.sh

Then follow the instructions on the terminal to add the printer.

Comment: @Zanna I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, nice work :) Maybe these comments can be cleaned up? You can flag them (or the post for mod attention) if so